# Selenium not able to recognize dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, testing

I was trying to recognize a dropdown and click/choose an organization out of the the below options

[image: Organization dropdown]

The inspect element of the dropdown's first element yields the below code

[image]

If you notice in the div style, the visibility is hidden. Do you think this is hampering the recognition of the organization dropdown. I am stuck on it past some days, please help.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of source code. Paste the actual code

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter it as an xpath like this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='css-1ac7191']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
// Your element.
@FindBy(id="select_2")
private WebElement gradeType;

// Code in method.
// Select grade drop down.
gradeType.click(); // It will click your drop down element.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='select_container_3']//*[text()='"+insert text+"']")).click(); // help to select your drop down
```